# Access key ID error when deploying with juju-core on non-ec2 ec2 clouds

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

juju-core (1.13) does not support the old pyjuju configuration variables `ec2-uri` and `s3-uri`.

So I took the Go sources and tweaked a new region in `launchpad.net/goamz/aws/aws.go` with the necessary API endpoints (GreenQloud).

Now juju bootstrap does not immediately say;

> error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our
>   records

Which it used to say immediately before making the change. Now it takes approx 15 seconds for it to give the same error. I added debug to `launchpad.net/juju-core/provider/ec2/ec2.go -> SetConfig()` and verified that it is passed through ok.

Any hints on what else could be possibly making requests to Amazon API instead of the GreenQloud endpoints I specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems the answer was in the juju-core README file which I didn't read well enough:

> ### --upload-tools
>
> The `juju` client program, and the juju 'tools' are deployed in
>   lockstep. When a release of `juju-core` is made, the compiled tools
>   matching that version of juju are extracted and uploaded to a known
>   location. This consumes a release version number, and implies that no
>   tools are available for the next, development, version of juju.
>   Therefore, when using the development version of juju you will need to
>   pass an additional flag, `--upload-tools` to instruct the `juju`
>   client to build a set of tools from source and upload them to the
>   environment as part of the bootstrap process.

Since I had built my own version to get GreenQloud as an AWS "region", I needed to include this parameter. The AWS error message is kinda weird, but anyway it disappeared after I included this parameter.

Now I'm faced with `error: cannot start bootstrap instance: no instance types found in greenqloud` but that is a different story :)